# Two optional arguments in batch

Tags: batch-file

How to make batch script that takes three optional parameters, but you can pass for example first and third parameter?
e.g.

```
@echo off
set FIRST_PARAM=%1
set SECOND_PARAM=%2
set THIRD_PARAM=%3

echo "%FIRST_PARAM%"
echo "%SECOND_PARAM%"
echo "%THIRD_PARAM%"
```

And if I put script_name.bat a b c it will give me

> "a"
>
> "b"
>
> "c"

but what if i want to pass only a and c and get

> "a"
>
> ""
>
> "c"

Is this possible?

Comment: Run `your_bat.bat "a" "" "c"` and you could see the result: should get exactly what you are asking for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass to the script `"a" "" "c"` and `""` will be the second parameter.

To dequote parameters you can use `%~1`:

```
@echo off
set "FIRST_PARAM=%~1"
set "SECOND_PARAM=%~2"
set "THIRD_PARAM=%~3"

echo "%FIRST_PARAM%"
echo "%SECOND_PARAM%"
echo "%THIRD_PARAM%"
```

or (dequoted and quoted again).`IF` is optional and checks for empty parameters.

```
@echo off
if "%~1" NEQ "" set "FIRST_PARAM="%~1""
if "%~2" NEQ "" set "SECOND_PARAM="%~2""
if "%~3" NEQ "" set "THIRD_PARAM="%~3""

echo "%FIRST_PARAM%"
echo "%SECOND_PARAM%"
echo "%THIRD_PARAM%"
```